# How can I apply selective color in Lightzone?

Tags: photo-editing

I'm using Lightzone to edit my raw files, and I'd like to apply some selective color to one of my images. I'd like to make it black and white, but leave one color still present in the image. How can I do this?

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but the current version of LightZone has a [forum](http://lightzoneproject.org/Forum) where you can ask. All of the insiders are good reliable sources of information, and I find that anything written by Doug Pardee is great. He tells you everything you need to know without getting bogged down in technicalities (when I want to know what time it is I don't want to be told how to build a clock).

Comment: @Unapiedra That is not correct. This is the [3-clause BSD license](http://opensource.org/licenses/BSD-3-Clause), a very permissive open source license. The software is under copyright (and all rights are reserved), **but** the license allows you (or anyone) to do many things, including redistribution, use, and modification. This is typical for open source software as opposed to public domain.

Comment: It is also the case for [Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/), which is the license applied to all of our contributions to this site. You and I retain copyright to our contributions, but allow other people to use the content we produce within the rules of the license.

Comment: @Unapiedra Let's delete all of these comments so as not to strew future confusion, okay? You go first. :)

Comment: @dpollitt you can download the code here: github.com/Aries85/LightZone (officially linked to from their front page).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the "Hue/Saturation" tool to choose the color (you can use the picker or select a primary), change saturation to -100, and check `Invert`.

[image: lightzone screenshot]